# General formula for Cholesky Entries

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the Cholesky decomposition of $A = LL^T, A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ how do we derive the formula for the entries of $A$ and $L$? I can't find the proof anywhere.
$$a_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{j} l_{ik}l_{jk}, \quad i \geq j. \\
l_{jj} = \pm\sqrt{a_{jj} - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} l_{jk}^2}, \\ l_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} l_{ik} l_{jk}}{l_{jj}}, \quad i \geq j 
$$

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is positive definite, the entries of $L$ can be found by forward substitution. Write
$$
A=\pmatrix{a&b^T\\ b&C},\ L=\pmatrix{x&0\\ v&L_1},\ LL^T=\pmatrix{x^2&xv^T\\ xv&L_1L_1^T+vv^T}.
$$
Then $x=\sqrt{a}$ and $v=\frac{1}{x}b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}b$, i.e. the first column of $L$ can be determined immediately. The remaining unknown is $L_1$. Since $C-vv^T=C-\frac{1}{a}bb^T$ is the Schur complement of $a$ in $A$, it is positive definite. Therefore $L_1L_1^T=C-vv^T$ is a Cholesky decomposition of a smaller-sized positive definite matrix and one may proceed recursively.